# inconsistent numpy FFT results

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, fft, dft

So I am measuring a signal from an ADC, the ADC has a 11.6 us sample time and reads exactly 60,000 samples each time. It is reading a signal from a pure sine wave generator (AD9850) that is generating a ~1V peak signal @ 1kHz.

I now feed the raw data from the ADC into an FFT method that uses numpy.fft, and that works just fine; I'm getting the right frequency.

The issue is with whether I pad the result or not!
When I use only the raw data, and returns a signal amplitude of 0.172.
Here's the code:

```
t_sample *= 1e-9                      #t_sample is given in ns
detrended = signal.detrend(data)      #remove DC component
length = len(detrended) 
fy = numpy.fft.fft(detrended)      
fy = 2.0*numpy.abs(fy)/length         #normalise the real component
size = len(fy)
fx = numpy.fft.fftfreq(size, t_sample)
return fx[:size/2+1],fy[:size/2+1]
```

Now when I tell the fft to pad out the array with a few extra zeros, to improve the calculation speed, the amplitude result becomes 0.513 - which is actually closer to the expected value for a 1V peak signal - but the fft noise floor is also higher. Here is the code:

```
t_sample *= 1e-9                         #t_sample is given in ns
detrended = signal.detrend(data)         #remove DC component
length = len(detrended)
NFFT = 2**int((math.ceil(math.log(length,2)))) 
fy = numpy.fft.fft(detrended, NFFT)      #normalise the real component
fy = 2.0*numpy.abs(fy)/length
fx = numpy.fft.fftfreq(NFFT, t_sample)
return fx[:NFFT/2],fy[:NFFT/2]
```

I'm assuming numpy.fft uses a different algorithm depending on the data structure, but why is there such a large difference in the result?

Comment: You'll get much more consistent results if you apply a suitable window function prior to the FFT, otherwise spectral leakage artefacts will give odd effects when you change the window size.

Comment: I agree with @PaulR, taper the data with windows like [Hamming](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hamming.html) or [Hann](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hann.html).

Comment: Are you sure that ``t_sample *= 1e-9``  is correct. Since ``t_sample`` is used in ``fftfreq()``, I would guess that your scaling changes on every run.

Comment: @Dietrich sorry, I've added a comment now, t_sample is given in ns, and I use a separate function to query the ADC for the sample time.

Comment: @PaulR I am new to FFT and frankly the mathematics is a bit beyond me, I'm learning about windowing now and I'll post when I've given it a shot

Comment: It's probably worth searching StackOverflow in regard to FFTs and window functions - I know this subject comes up regularly and there are some good answers available. The [Wikipedia page on window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) is quite good too.